# error uninstalling phpmyadmin from debian 7

Tags: phpmyadmin, debian, uninstallation, dpkg

I have a cubieboard with debian 7 and yesterday I installed phpmyadmin, it was working great but today I had to shut down the machine and when I bring it on again, the phpmyadmin page showed only ������.

I'm trying to uninstall the phpmyadmin from my machine but I get this error:

```
    apt-get purge phpmyadmin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dbconfig-common javascript-common libgd3 libjbig0 libjpeg62-turbo
  libjs-jquery libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libmcrypt4 libtiff5 libvpx1
  libxpm4 php-gettext php-tcpdf php5-gd php5-mcrypt
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  phpmyadmin*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 37 not upgraded.
After this operation, 24.5 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $item in hash element at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 85, <__ANONIO__> chunk 1.
Use of uninitialized value $item in hash element at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 85, <__ANONIO__> chunk 4.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'phpmyadmin' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your system has some other odd problem aside from the phpMyAdmin difficulty, I found this thread: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debconf/+bug/13130 which suggests:
* `sudo dpkg-reconfigure debconf`
* `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
* `sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*.dat` followed by `sudo dpkg-reconfigure debconf`

About phpMyAdmin, if you still have trouble after reinstalling, try forcing your web browser to reload the page (not just a refresh; on my browser that's accomplished by holding shift while clicking the reload/refresh button), clear any browser cookies starting with pma, and try clearing the browser cache.

Comment: it looks like that doesn't work in debian, but thanks

Comment: Which part exactly doesn't work? As far as I know, apt won't work without dpkg, and your apt looks like it's working so I'm a bit confused.